Android webview with fcm: browser doesn't support firebase SDK
I want to show a web using Android app view, and I want to use fcm on that web.
But, errors  occurs.
I've searched every articles about this, but haven't found exact answer yet.
Error message
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", source: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js (1)
Application finished.

Version

Chrome browser: 91
Firebase:  13.7.2

Trouble shooting

Set the Android's default browser to Chrome.
Set url using https. my url is "https://~~"

But, errors still occurs.
I'm waiting for any kind of answer...
